# Is it possible to gain extra uses of unique class features?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Some classes offer unique powers as class features with a number of uses per day. Is there any possible way to increase the number?

For example:

- **A Thousand Cuts (Ex)**: When a dervish reaches 10th level, once per day she may double the number of melee attacks she makes while performing a full attack action (whether in a dervish dance or not). If a dervish uses this ability in conjunction with her dervish dance, she can make up to two attacks between moves.
- **Lucky (Ex)**: Many swashbucklers live by the credo "Better lucky than good." Once per day, a swashbuckler of 11th level or higher may re-roll any failed attack roll, skill check, ability check, or saving throw. The character must take the result of the re-roll, even if it's worse than the original roll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The right squire of legend can help in these specific cases…

A creature that takes the prestige class squire of legend (*Complete Champion* 110–2), picks as his paragon's path the fallen hero Reikhardt, and advances to level 2 gains Reikhardt's lesser squire's burden, a supernatural ability usable once per day that says

> You can grant an ally within 30 feet a second use of an extraordinary or supernatural ability normally usable only once per day. If you gain a second daily use of this [lesser squire's burden] ability, you cannot use it twice in one day on the same ally.

While this means there's a dude following around and cheering on your swashbuckler/dervish, that's actually kind of in genre. (The text says specifically that a squire can't use these kinds of abilities on himself, although possibly a *squad* of squires of legend *could* use them on *each other*. Ask the DM.)

Otherwise, however, [Topquark's pretty much nailed it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80851/8610) in that if you're looking for another Wizards of the Coast way to get extra uses of a class feature *generally*, you're out of luck and left hoping *something* was published that increases the number of times that class feature specifically can be used.

### …And you can also look to licensed material

AEG's [*The Hidden Emperor*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594720347) (2005)—a Wizards of the Coast officially licensed product—includes the feat **Heart of Suitengu** (16), which has as its benefit the following:

> Once per day, by taking 1 hour to meditate and spending a Void Point, you may select one Class Feature that has a limited number of uses per day (other than Spells and Spell Use); your number of uses refreshes as though you had spent a day of rest.

The Heart of Suitengu feat's prerequisites are 1 level of monk, shugenja, or inkyo (a setting-specific base class from [*Rokugan*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1887953388) 41-4—also a Wizards of the Coast officially licensed product) plus the feat Void Use (55-6), the latter feat making this feat challenging for a nonhuman, non-Rokugani creature to acquire. [There's an argument](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74346/8610) that allows even a nonhuman, non-Rokugani with but 1 level of inkyo to gain the feat Void Use then to take immediately—as the creature's level 1 inkyo kiho feat (similar to a fighter's bonus feat)—the feat Heart of Suitengu.

If you've already one level of inkyo, monk, or shugenja, an even more generous DM may allow you to take the feat Heart of Suitengu upon acquiring "all the advantages of the Void Use feat" *via* the *amulet of the void* ([*Secrets of the Phoenix*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1887953787) 61—still officially licensed) (8,000 gp; 0 lbs.).

Were I the DM for a traditional *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* campaign in which a player wanted the feat Heart of Suitengu so his PC dervish's a thousand cuts or swashbuckler's lucky extraordinary abilities could be used a second time per day, I'd have no problem with the PC taking one level of inkyo to get the feat (or whatever workaround's needed to meet the feat Heart of Suitengu's prerequisites). I would, however, look askance at a player who, for example, wanted his PC to take a level of inkyo so that as a level 10 master of the secret sound (*Dragon* #297 78-9) the PC could use the spell-like ability *the secret sound* a second time per day. (I mean, really *wish* as a spell-like ability *once* per day should be enough.)

Comment: Is it some way to use Heart of Suitengu faster than 1 hour meditation? That would be the best possible answer!

Comment: @Momonga-sama *The Hidden Emperor* (Sept. 2005) is the very last of AEG's Oriental Adventures line. The feat was not supported beyond that text, and I'm unaware of any way to meditate (as described in the feat's benefit) faster. Sorry, man.

Answer (score 6):

There are specific feats for specific class features, but no generic way. These feats include:

- Extra Granted Maneuver (Crusader's maneuvers)
- Extra Music (Bard's music +4/day)
- Extra Rage (Barbarian's rage +2/day)
- Extra Readied Maneuver (Swordsage's maneuvers +1/encounter)
- Extra Slot (any spellcaster's spell slots +1/day)
- Extra Smiting (Paladin's smite +2/day)
- Extra Stunning (Monk's stunning fist +3/day)
- Extra Turning (Cleric/Paladin's turn undead +4/day)
- Extra Wild Shape (Druid's wild shape +2/day)
- Magic In The Blood (all racial SLAs +2/day)

However, most class features of non-core classes (such as the ones you mentioned), don't have any such feat. There just isn't any way.

Comment: Technically, any player could talk to their DM about creating a custom feat, using the above as guidelines. It might be better to say there is no "standard" or "universally accepted/legal" way to do so.